# Django Model Charfield many Choices automatically create?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add some choices between year 1950 to 2020. How can i do that?

```
a = 1950
while a < 2020:
    b=a + 1
YEAR_CHOICES = (
    ('b', 'b'),
)
class Sezonlar(models.Model):
    sezon = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for that [`choices` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) is just:

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field.

So you can construct it using a list comprehension like so:

```
YEAR_CHOICES = [(str(yr), str(yr)) for yr in range(1950, 2020)]
```